# Windows IoT startup app

Tags: windows, arduino, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I have a problem with Windows IoT startup app, I choose my app to be startup. This works good but when I reset Rpi 2 or 3 via external arduino through RUN pin windows reboots and start my app but after approximately 30 seconds app is replaced by default IoT core app and removed from startup too. Do you know where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the official sample [HelloWorld](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples) and set it as startup app by [WDP](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal) tool?

Comment: yeah, that is thw way I did it.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you do "shutdonw /r /t 0"?